# Change HTML file under certain circumstances

Tags: php, html

I have various html files in which I need to fill 3 Code snippets at 3 different positions. once directly after head starts, once in beginning and once in the end of the body.

I know where those html files are, cause I have a database for some other reasons, where I can also track down the html-files.

So I can run my php, getting all the files from  database, then I need to check if my codesnippets are already existing in each file, if they do I do nothing, if not I need to add the snippets.

Even so php might not be the best choice, I do not have the time for now to learn something new (even though I appreciate tips, with which language this would work best for later)

I checked similar posts, but I can´t find the answer i´m seeking for

Comment: Nono, I can´t start with C# or equal things right now, I want to finish it within a week, next to alot of other tasks on my list. So I just need a quick info which functions of php I use and some start help. I just hoped for some tips actually I will ofc do it myself, I just got some time pressure since my boss has new ideas every day and I am the only developer right now....

Comment: down-voting for low research effort.  A google search for "PHP write to file" or "PHP edit file" yields all kinds of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's helpful to distinguish between a "file" and a "filename."  When you say that you will be "getting all the files from database,"  I assume you mean that you'll be getting the filenames from the database.

If so, you can use the PHP "file_get_contents" function to read the file contents into a string.  Then you can search the string (using various string functions such as "strpos" or "stripos") to see if it contains the HTML snippet you're looking for.

If the HTML snipped you're looking for isn't there, you can modify the string (again using various string functions) to add it. Search the PHP documentation for "string functions" since there are different ways to go about doing this.

When you're done you can write the altered string back to file using the "file_put_contents" function.

I won't go into the function syntax since you will, of course, want to research that in the PHP documentation regardless of what you read here.

There may be other problems with file permissions.  If you get errors that you can't write to a file, you'll need to look into the chmod function.